# How I can select a folder destination in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, path, directory

I would like to know how can I select a directory of a destination folder in MVC like the folderbrowserdialog?

Like this image http://www.codeguru.com/img/legacy/files/getFolder1.gif

For example, if I select a folder I want to get the path like \Server\Folder1\Folder11

Thanks!

Comment: There is no browser-provided "browse for folder" dialog (since there is not much value in it). Consider editing your question with explanation what "destination folder" is and what you expect to achieve as result. Note that WebForms don't have `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` class either...

Comment: Thank you for your answer I this I make a mistake is in Windows Forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xca5d950.aspx

Comment: Your question is still very unclear - please comment on if "MVC" is "ASP.Net MVC" and what you expect to achieve as result of showing a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

Some chat u can find there

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10116970/accessing-shared-folder-on-a-network-using-c-code.aspx

**Snippet 1:**

```
List<string> mappedDrives = new List<string>();
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (DriveInfo drvInfo in drives)
{
          if (drvInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
            mappedDrives.Add(drvInfo.Name);
}
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
ManagementScope mgmtScope = new ManagementScope();
//query for drivetype = 4..for  network drive
ObjectQuery objQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT VolumeName FROM Win32_LogicalDisk   WHERE DriveType= 4");
ManagementObjectSearcher mgmgObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope,   objQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection mgmgObjColl = mgmgObjSearch.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mgmgObj in mgmgObjColl)
{
    mappedDrives.Add(mgmgObj["VolumeName"].ToString());
}
```